# How can I extract and sum the odd digits of an integer

Tags: java, for-loop, numbers

I have a problem writing a program that takes an input of a number like 32677, taking out the odd digits and adding them together. For the digit in position 0 is 3. Since 3 is not divisible by 2 store 3 and add it into the sum. Check the digit in position 1 which is 2. 2 is divisible by 2 so do not store it, discard it and check the next digit.

Check the digit in position 2, which is 6, 6 is divisibleby 2 so discard it and check the next digit. Check number in position 3, which is 7. Check if 7 is divisible by 2, store 7 and add it with odd digit, which is 3. The total is 10.

check the next and last digit in position 4 which is 7. Check if 7 is divisible by 2. It is not so store it and add it with the other odd digits, which is 3+7+7 = 17.

I only get 7 when I run the program. I am supposed to get 17 as the answer.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             //Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
             System.out.println("Input an a number: ");
             //int userInput = in.nextInt();
             int oddSum = 0;
             int storedNum = 32677;
             int inputLength = 5;
             for (int inputPosition = 0; inputPosition < inputLength; inputPosition ++) {
                 for (int i = 0; i < inputLength; i++ ) {
                 storedNum = storedNum % 10;
        
             if (storedNum % 2 == 1) {
                 int oddNum = storedNum;
                 oddSum = oddNum + oddSum; 
                 storedNum = storedNum / 10;
        }
                 else {
                 storedNum = storedNum / 10;
                 }
             }
             }
             System.out.printf("%d", oddSum);
             //scanner.close();
     }
        
     }
```

Comment: Why is `inputLength` 4 if the number has 5 digits?

Comment: Because in programming it starts to count the position from 0. Meaning 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 Which in total is 5. We do not start to count with 1. We set the counter to 0 and start count from there.

Comment: Also, if the first thing you do is overwriting your number with the result of `storedNum % 10`, well, the result of that is 7, so...

Comment: By the way, no, we don't start counting from 0, we index arrays starting from 0. But when we're counting stuff we can start from 10000 and go to 10004 to count five elements, for what it's worth. But that's not the point. The algorithm is wrong either way.

Comment: I just want to take out the single number from the full number which is 32677. I want to take out 7, 7 and 3. Discarding 2 and 6 as these are even. I want to take out the odd numbers and add them together.

Comment: What you want to do is clear. But it's not what you're doing. Again, consider `storedNum = storedNum % 10;` If `storedNum` is 32677 before that instruction, what will its value be *after* the statement?

Comment: In other words, that should probably be something like `int lastDigit = storedNum % 10` and the subsequent `if` should check `lastDigit`, not `storedNum`.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by this way :

```java
int num = 32677;
int sum = 0;

while(num > 0) {
    int lastDigit = num % 10;

    if (lastDigit % 2 != 0)
        sum += lastDigit;

    num = num / 10;
}

System.out.print(sum);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. How do I make a program that takes in x amount of inputs from the user, knows if the number the user entered consists of 2 or 5 digits, and by that takes out each number separately and makes the calculation?

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 
  System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
  int inputNumber = in.nextInt();
  int sum = 0;
  
  while(inputNumber > 0) {
   int lastDigit = inputNumber % 10;
   if (lastDigit % 2 != 0) 
    sum = sum + lastDigit;
    inputNumber = inputNumber / 10;
   
   
   System.out.printf("d%", sum);
   in.close(); 
   }
  }
 }